# Jquery form serialize issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a form

```
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test2" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test3" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test4" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test5" /><br />
<input type="text" name="test6" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" /><br /></form>
```

And i wrote a jquery ajax script like this

```
$(":input[ name= 'submit']").click(function(){

    var values = $("form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url:"test.php",
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            method: "test",
            data: values
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }   
    }); 
    return false;   
});
```

> `data: {
>               method: "test",
>               data: values
>           }`

But when i pass two parameters in ajax.data element, i cannot access it as $_POST['name'] or $_POST['test1'] at server side. But it is possible if i add only one parameter to the ajax.data element.

Please get me a solution

Answer (score 2):

The .serialize method already converts the form values into key/value pairs that must be sent as-is to the server. If you want to pass additional values you could use a hidden field in the form.

Like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="method" name="method" value="test" />

    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="test1" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="test2" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="test3" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="test4" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="test5" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="test6" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" /><br />
</form>
```

and then:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: values,
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }   
    }); 
    return false;   
});
```

and if you need to set some other value just before sending the AJAX request:

```
$('#method').val('some other value');
```

Also notice that I subscribed to the .submit event of the form instead of the click event of the submit button which will also properly handle the case when the user presses the Enter key while inside some of the input elements, whereas your code won't be triggered because the submit button was never clicked and yet the form was submitted.

Comment: i just want to know why is that happening

Comment: It's happening because as I already stated in my answer the .serialize method converts the form values into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request ready to be sent as-is. In your case you are modifying this by adding some other elements and break this convention. You should not be modifying the data parameter once you serialize it.

Comment: I don't see what how is this related to the problem. Yes, there is another possibility. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4807324/29407 and more specifically the `serializeObject` plugin shown.

Comment: When i enter $_POST['data'] it gives me an output like "name=abc&test1=&test2=&test3=&test4=&test5=&test6=" but echo $_POST['data']['name'] gives me "n".Why?

Comment: Did you use the .serializeObject plugin I've linked to? In your script you could fetch the values like that `$_POST['method']` and `$_POST['data[name]']`, ... assuming you sent the request like that: `data: { data: $(this).serializeObject(), method: 'some value' }`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9589/discussion-between-user1066679-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: Well then I guess the hidden field is the way to go. Good luck.

Comment: however when use json its fail to do ajax call ... without it its success request .. or may be i am mistaken ..

Comment: This is GREAT ANSWARE!

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
   data: values,
```

in this way you can get your data `$_POST['test1']`;

if you need to send extra  data use hidden fields

EDIT if you use two fields like in your exampel you will have the data in `$_POST['data']` (here you will have the serialized form) and  `$_POST['method']`

EDIT 2 actually `$_POST['data']` is a string (`name=abc&test1=&test2=&test3=&test4=&test5=&test6=` ) because a string is set to the server, if you access  `$_POST['data']['name']`, this returns `n` because in php you can access string as arrays, in your case you are not passing a valid index and it returns the first characther

```
$name = "aghjsghjgj";
echo $name['name'];//this echoes the first letter as name is not a valid index

echo $name[2];//this echoies the third letter , h
```

http://codepad.org/ferFnrKW

Comment: but why php cannot get that if i pass two arguments.Please describe

Comment: OK when i enter echo $_POST['data'];

It gives me an output like name=abc&test1=&test2=&test3=&test4=&test5=&test6=

but when i enter $_POST['data']['name'] it gives me "n".Why?

Comment: @user1066679 there is no `$_POST['data']['name']`, i edited my aanswer